# Windows 8 installer stuck at "Getting ready"

Tags: windows, windows-8

It has been stuck since 1 hour. I read that removing the CD fixes the problem, but I'm installing it from the C:/ drive(Enterprise evaluation version), so I can't remove it... What should I do?

Comment: Does this thread @ Microsoft Community help? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-professional-installation-hangs-freezes/3bf40c3e-ed77-46bd-b379-386f8c489884